# Firestore Aggregation - Fanout and Update Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a document to distribute inside other documents based on an array of IDs inside the original document.

Original Document;

```
name: ABC
image: https://.....g.png
duplicateTo: [someID1, someID2, someID3]
```

How do i distribute this document to documents that has the duplicateTO ID. And if an ID is deleted from original document's duplicateTO array does nodejs' **onUpdate** knows it? Can I also delete the distributed data from the target documents?

How do we do it? Thank you,